# how to reduce the size of core_url_rewrite: Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a lot of entries in the table core_url_rewrite, how can I reduce ? I'm using magento 1.9.x
Actually the table has ~3,680,554 records and 2.5 GB of size. I put in the pas about 100 redirect (manually), I cant clear it, just to delete the unnecessary records.

regards

Comment: How many products do you have in your database?

Comment: I have 3,000 sku aprox

Answer (score 1):

You can truncate `core_url_rewrite` and run re-indexing to regenerate URLs.

First execute this on Database:

```
TRUNCATE core_url_rewrite;
```

then execute this on shell to re-index url rewrites table:

```
php -f ./shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
```

**Note:**
There is a problem with this criteria.

- All the additional URL rewrites that you had manually generated would be lost
- All the redirects from old URL to new URL would gone to 404 (Not good for SEO) either related to category or product

I would suggest you first take backup of your code before doing this.

Hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Many thanks, this is my concern, I need keep all the manual redirects. The SEO is very important for me

Comment: Then I would recommend you just ignore the size of `core_url_rewrite` if redirect URLs are important for you.